# Can I split an EaseUS ToDo backup between multiple drives?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, easeus-todo-backup

I have one large hard drive of 3TB that I would like to do incremental/differential automatic backups on to 3x 1TB drives.

How can I make EaseUS Todo backup to split the backup archive across these three drives automatically?

Additionally, if this *is* possible, then if I lose one of the backup drives, can I still read the files that exist on the remaining ones?

I have EaseUS Todo Backup Free 6.0 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: What version of the program are you using? What version of Windows are you using?  If you split the archive created ( not saying its possible ) but the archive would then be incomplete and could not be used.

Answer (score 0):

This looks possibe according to [their webpage](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/features/backup-image-splitting.htm)

Looks like you need to go Backup -> File backup, and select the Splitting tab.

Unfortunately, this still looks like it'll require a single target, i.e one path to save the files to, rather than allowing you to specify to put part 1 on disk 1, part 2 on disk 2, etc.

As for your second question, the note on that page makes it sound unlikely that you'd be able to recover the files if you lose one of the parts:

> Note: Images can be split into several files to fit the type of the
>   storage media, it depends on the file system of the destination
>   storage media. Please make sure all the splitted images are stored
>   under the same folder so that restore can be achieved successfully.

I think you might be better off trying to combine your 3 drives into a single target using RAID, and backing up there, but you'd still be at risk of individual drive failure, unless willing to use a parity bit a la RAID5 (and thus giving up some storage).

Comment: Thanks for the input, i have though of spanning the three 1tb drives into a single 3tb volume to store the backups, it just sounds so unneccesary to loose all the data if one drive fails, when in theory all the files that are completly on any one drive should still be intact, and only the files who are partially present on more than one drive should be corrypted by the loss.  This is why i am using a backup solution in the first place, and not raid or spanning... I am willing to accept the loss of a drive, but not the data on all three drives if one is lost.

Comment: Yeah, the issue with using these types of backup solutions is that most use a proprietary archive format (especially for incremental backups), so recovery can be difficult.  Just copying files in a scheduled task or what not might be a better fit if you want to have high flexibility to the backups.

Comment: I agree, I might end up with a batch script. the only problem is that this computer is used as a nas, which means that large files are transferred to it, which means that there are partial files present most of the time. This means that i can not reliably skip existing files, but would have to overwrite all files periodically... Ideally i would just buy another 3TB drive, mirror it with the existing 3TB drive, then put the 3x 1TB drives in a raid 5, but i have had some bad experiences with mirroring before, where the whole array was corrupted by the loss of a single drive, still dont know why.

Comment: This has made me trust only simple drives with the complete files on them... I just need something that could help me spread them across multiple drives... Also, dealing with many drives is always a pain, and it would be better to have one large volume, i jsut need some redundancy is all...